# Repeat a piece of job at the beginning of every Spring Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring Framework and I am wondering what is the best way to implement some jobs that repeat in almost every controller. For example, currently in every controller, I have to check if the client user is authorized to this controller or not based on a relationship table in the DB, and then retrieve the sidebar menu from DB, and so on... before I actually start my coding for this controller.

So, is there any way that I can save these repeated codes in somewhere and then inject them to a desired list of controllers so that they are called whenever a controller is used. Thanks

Comment: Put that common code in a servlet filter or a Spring interceptor. Or in an AOP Aspect.

Comment: Or `ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: Go through `Spring-Security` roles concept and `hasAuthority` annotation.